# TableViewController not recognizing object after imported the objects .h file

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray

I have created an object (object name is Coach) and I have declared an array property for that object in its .h file`@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray *interestingCoaches;` and `@property (strong, nonatomic) Coach *coach;` then in a view controller (lets call it xViewController) I imported the Coach.h file (`#import "Coach.h"`) and set the array self.coach.interestingCoaches. However in my table view controller, I imported my Coach.h file and when I try and set my `- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView` method to

`return self.coach.interestingCoaches.count;`

it says that "property coach" is not found and forces me to recreate the coach property

`@property (strong, nonatomic) Coach *coach;`
in the table view controller's heading again. Why does it recognize the coach object in my XViewController and not in my table view controller? and how do I have my table view controller recognize the object with the array that was declared in my xViewController?

thanks (no story boards)

Answer (score 0):

How I understand the setup:
You have a Coach class with a property: NSArray intrestingCoaches.
You have a XViewController class with a property: Coach coach.
You have a UITableViewController class.

If you set the array of the coach in the XViewController class and you want to access the same array in your UITableViewController class, you will need a ***reference*** to the same coach.

I cannot see how your classes are set up, so I cannot give a complete answer. Here is what I think you want:

You have your XViewController and you want to show the UITableViewController. 
I think the best option would be to keep a coach reference in your UITableViewController.
So you have to make a custom UITableViewController:

```
@interface CustomTableViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) Coach *coach;

@end
```

When you init the CustomTableViewController:

```
CustomTableViewController *tableViewController = [CustomTableViewController alloc]init];
tableViewController.coach = self.coach       //self = XViewController
//Show view
```

Now you have a reference to the same coach!
Don't forget about setting the Delegate and Data Source.

Correct me if my understanding of your setup is wrong, so I can edit my answer!